# Connection always dropping?

Tags: dual-boot, 17.04

I am typing this in my phone as I don't have an internet connection in my computer to post this so I apologise for bad details, layout and spelling in  advance as I did rush it a little.

When trying to connect on my new installation on Ubuntu I get the connecting animation for about 30 seconds then get told I was disconnected.

This happens for Wi-Fi and wired connections, so I can't download any of the drivers or anything to fix this like other tutorials suggested

I am using 17.0.4 please help?

Comment: Maybe check the logs or you can try restarting the network manager by running `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`

Comment: Where would I find the logs? First time Ubuntu user.